# Sum of a sequence is smaller than 1

Tags: sequences-and-series

I try to understand a step in a proof.

First, we define $\epsilon_n=1-\delta_0 - \delta_1-...-\delta_n$, where $\sum_j \delta_j =1$ and $\delta_j > 0 \ \forall j$.

> > Claim: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e_n \leq 1.$$

This is not so clear for me. Can somebody proof that or say why this is true?

Comment: Why do you think it is true?

Comment: Note sure about your delta sum - it would mean a non positive epsilon, which would be unusual.

Comment: I edited my question, because I did a mistake for the $\delta_j$'s... They are strictly positiver than 0.

Comment: Source of the problem? (I modified the tag, which was *really* odd.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Pick $\delta_i = 0$ for $i \ne 2$ and $\delta_2 = 1$. Then 
$\epsilon_0 = \epsilon_1 = 1$, and $\epsilon_i = 0$ for $i > 1$. So $\sum_i \epsilon_i = 2$.

Since the poster says now that the deltas are supposed to be strictly positive, this becomes:

This is false. Pick 
$$
\delta_i = 0.001
$$ 
for $i = 0, 1$ and 
$$
\delta_i = \frac{.998}{2^{i-1}}
$$ 
for $i > 1$.

Then 
$\epsilon_0 = 0.999; \epsilon_1 =  0.998$, and $\epsilon_i \ge 0$ for $i > 1$. So at the very least $\sum_i \epsilon_i \ge \sum_{i = 0,1} \epsilon_i > 1.9 > 1$.

Comment: Thank you! But I did a silly msitake with the $\delta_j$... They are strictly positiver than 0! I edited it!